# Radix sort get the right key to sort signed integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I have a trouble with finding a right value for sorting with radix sorting algorithm.
I have implemented it right, but I have an issue with negatives. I tried just to reverse value with a binary. It helped me a little, but negatives are in ascending order instead of being in descending order. Funniest thing is that sorting works fine with floating points and signed integers.

Here is my function to build a key for sorting:

```
uint32_t SortKeyToU32(int Value)
{
    uint32_t Result = (uint32_t)Value;
    if(Result & 0x80000000)
    {
        Result = ~Result;
    }
    else
    {
        Result |= 0x80000000;
    }
    return Result;
}
```

And here is my sorting function:

```
void RadixSort(int** Array, int Size)
{
    int* Dest   = new int[Size];
    int* Source = *Array;
    memset(Dest, 0, Size*sizeof(int));

    for(int Bit = 0;
        Bit < 32;
        Bit += 8)
    {
        uint32_t ArrayOfValues[256] = {};
        for(int Index = 0;
            Index < Size;
            ++Index)
        {
            uint32_t SortKey = SortKeyToU32(Source[Index]);
            uint32_t Key = (SortKey >> Bit) & 0xFF;
            ++ArrayOfValues[Key];
        }

        int Sum = 0;
        for (int Index = 0;
            Index < ArraySize(ArrayOfValues);
            ++Index)
        {
            uint32_t Count = ArrayOfValues[Index];
            ArrayOfValues[Index] = Sum;
            Sum += Count;
        }

        for(int Index = 0;
            Index < Size;
            ++Index)
        {
            uint32_t SortKey = SortKeyToU32(Source[Index]);
            uint32_t Key = (SortKey >> Bit) & 0xFF;
            Dest[ArrayOfValues[Key]++] = Source[Index];
        }

        int* Temp = Source;
        Source = Dest;
        Dest = Temp;
    }
}
```

But how can I deal with sorting signed integers? Sorry if it is looks obvious. Thanks.

EDIT.
Here is sample array input: 1, 6, 9, 2, 3, -4, -10, 8, -30, 4

Output: -4, -10, -30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9

Comment: Pleas add a small failing example, the desired output and debug information.

Comment: I added addition sample input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Radix Sort for Negative Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306665/radix-sort-for-negative-integers) (Note: I suggest using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52472629/1377097) rather than the accepted one.)

Comment: Whell, It almost worked for me. I tried to flip the sign with simple Value = -Value. I got this result: -4, -10, -30, 9, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1

Comment: You need to flip only the sign bit, not do a two's complement of the number. For example, 0x01234567 with sign bit flipped becomes 0x81234567.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort key formula that you need is very simple:

```cpp
uint32_t SortKeyToU32(int32_t Value) {
    return uint32_t(Value) + (1U << 31);
}
```

the reason for it following. First we cast from 32-bit signed to unsigned. This casting just reinterprets bits of signed value as unsigned.

Lets see how signed values are presented in value space of a number. For simplicity lets see on 4-bit signed number, it has 16 different values in total mapped as following:

Signed form:

`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,   -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1`

Unsigned form:

`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,    8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15`

In signed case first half of values are non-negative in ascending order and exactly second half are negative values also in ascending order.

For sorting we need all negative values go before positive and also in ascending order. For signed 4-bit values above (in unsigned form) we need just to add `8`, this is exactly middle of a range. Thus whole range will shift right with overflow and negative values will appear before positives (below first number is number after adding `8`, second number (in parenthesis) is original (before adding)):

`0 (-8), 1 (-7), 2 (-6), 3 (-5), 4 (-4), 5 (-3), 6 (-2), 7 (-1), 8 (0), 9 (1), 10 (2), 11 (3), 12 (4), 13 (5), 14 (6), 15 (7)`

This is exactly what I did in my sort key formula

`uint32_t(Value) + (1U << 31)`

I reinterpret-casted signed to unsigned form and added middle-range value which is `(1U << 31)`.

With this corrected formula your code works right way, in snippet below I left your original sort key formula too under name `SortKeyToU32Old()` you may change names of sort key functions to see how it works before (incorrectly) and after (correctly) change on my example array.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/3Pq7h1vs5)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

#define ArraySize(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))

uint32_t SortKeyToU32(int32_t Value) {
    return uint32_t(Value) + (1U << 31);
}

uint32_t SortKeyToU32Old(int Value)
{
    uint32_t Result = (uint32_t)Value;
    if(Result & 0x80000000)
    {
        Result = ~Result;
    }
    else
    {
        Result |= 0x80000000;
    }
    return Result;
}

void RadixSort(int** Array, int Size)
{
    int* Dest   = new int[Size];
    int* Source = *Array;
    memset(Dest, 0, Size*sizeof(int));

    for(int Bit = 0;
        Bit < 32;
        Bit += 8)
    {
        uint32_t ArrayOfValues[256] = {};
        for(int Index = 0;
            Index < Size;
            ++Index)
        {
            uint32_t SortKey = SortKeyToU32(Source[Index]);
            uint32_t Key = (SortKey >> Bit) & 0xFF;
            ++ArrayOfValues[Key];
        }

        int Sum = 0;
        for (int Index = 0;
            Index < ArraySize(ArrayOfValues);
            ++Index)
        {
            uint32_t Count = ArrayOfValues[Index];
            ArrayOfValues[Index] = Sum;
            Sum += Count;
        }

        for(int Index = 0;
            Index < Size;
            ++Index)
        {
            uint32_t SortKey = SortKeyToU32(Source[Index]);
            uint32_t Key = (SortKey >> Bit) & 0xFF;
            Dest[ArrayOfValues[Key]++] = Source[Index];
        }

        int* Temp = Source;
        Source = Dest;
        Dest = Temp;
    }
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a[] = {1000, -200, 800, -300, 900, -100};
    int * p = &a[0];
    RadixSort(&p, ArraySize(a));
    for (auto x: a)
        std::cout << x << " ";
}
```

Input:

`{1000, -200, 800, -300, 900, -100}`

Output (correct, new sort key):

`-300 -200 -100 800 900 1000`

Output (incorrect, original sort key):

`-100 -200 -300 800 900 1000`

Comment: Wouldn't be `return uint32_t(Value) ^ (1U << 31);` safer?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie What do you mean by `safer`? Adding `+ (1U << 31)` works totally correct for any 32-bit unsigned value, there is no exception. Adding two unsigned 32 bit values of any magnitude is totally safe even with overflow. For me even if overflow occurs, I still get correct value, actually I rely on overflow to occur always for all negative values (upper half of range). Why I do precisely `+ (1U << 31)` and not something else - because this gives us idea of Centering, basically signed values are centered around value `1U << 31`, negative values will go below this value, positive above.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie If you know any exception when `+ (1U << 31)` doesn't work correctly while yours `^ (1U << 31)` works, please tell me this concrete number-exception, I'll re-check my formula.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such an excellent answer and for such easy to understand explanation. Thank you.